# User input stored in array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xhtml

Hi guys i'm kinda new to javascript and for a while now, i've been struggeling with something that shouldnt be that hard. The thing that i'm trying to execute is to get user input stored in an array, and then get it to print the collected info into a specific div (later on i'm gonna try to create a table using the DOM and store the input there). But i cant get it to work, below is my code :) any suggestions?

```
    JavaScript

    function submitInfo(){

    var nameInput = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var ageInput = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var fsInput = document.getElementById("fightingStyle").value;
    var weightInput = document.getElementById("weight").value;

    myArray[0]=nameInput;
    myArray[1]=ageInput;
    myArray[2]=fsInput;
    myArray[3]=weightInput;

    for(var i = 0; i<myArray.lenght; i++){
    document.getElementById("theResult").innerHTML=myArray[i];
    }

    }

    HTML

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="inl2a.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inl2a.js"></script>
    <title>Inlämning 2a</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="inputFields">
    <h3>Submit your fighters information:</h3>

    Name:<br><br>
    <input id="name" type="text" /><br><br>
    Age:<br><br>
    <input id="age" type="text" /><br><br>
    Fighting style:<br><br>
    <input id="fightingStyle" type="text" /><br><br>
    Weight:<br><br>
    <input id="weight" type="text" /><br><br>

    <input id="button" value="Submit" type="button" onclick="submitInfo();" /><br><br>
    </div>

    <div id="theResult">
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function submitInfo(){
    var myArray = []; // problem 1

    var nameInput = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var ageInput = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var fsInput = document.getElementById("fightingStyle").value;
    var weightInput = document.getElementById("weight").value;

    myArray[0]=nameInput;
    myArray[1]=ageInput;
    myArray[2]=fsInput;
    myArray[3]=weightInput;

    for(var i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++){ // problem 3
        document.getElementById("theResult").innerHTML+=myArray[i]; // problem 2
    }

}
```

1. you haven't initialized the array anywhere
2. you overwrite the innerHTML property so only the last value remains
3. you have a typo: lenght instead of length

You can also set the values directly in the array and no longer use the intermediary variables. Also, you can get theResult element once, outside of the loop:

```
function submitInfo(){
    var myArray = []; // problem 1

    myArray.push(document.getElementById("name").value);
    myArray.push(document.getElementById("age").value);
    myArray.push(document.getElementById("fightingStyle").value);
    myArray.push(document.getElementById("weight").value);

    var element = document.getElementById("theResult");

    for(var i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++){
        element.innerHTML += myArray[i]; // problem 2
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, is there any quick way to assign the input to a new row element?

Comment: Sure, instead of adding it to #theResult, you can create a new tr, create a new td for each value and just append the td's as children of the tr and the tr as child of the table. I am assuming your data is tabular in nature, otherwise you would be advised to not use tables.

Answer (score 0):

suppose user inputs are title and name, then

```
var title   = document.getElementById("title").value;
var name    = document.getElementById("name").value;
```

You could put all of these in one array:

```
var m = [ title, name ];
```

then for `title` use,

```
document.getElementById(your_divID).innerText=m[0];
```

you can use `textContent` instead of `innerText` for mozilla support.